# Using the js library in the flutter project

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm new to flutter, I have a flutter project that I'm building for android, ios and web. And only in the web build do I need to use the js library to encrypt api requests. Here is this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@expressms/smartapp-bridge and she's not very good, as far as I'm concerned. This is a requirement of the client and he provides this library. I can't rewrite it in dart. I have to use js callbacks for encryption and decryption in every api call. And I can't do it. I figured out what to use https://pub.dev/packages/js but it's too complicated for me. Maybe there is a good example with code?

```js
@JS()
library web.js;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:medlike/app.dart';


import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS()
@anonymous
abstract class WebBridge {
  external void constructor();
  external factory WebBridge();
  external void addGlobalListener();
  external void enableLogs();
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  runApp(App());

  var bridge = WebBridge();
  print(bridge.toString());
}
```

Comment: this library has features, it's a bit strange. But I also can't use any js libraries in my project

Comment: you can use flutter provided dart:js and create your library functions under web using script. Here is a good example of calling js functions from dart - https://fireship.io/snippets/using-js-with-flutter-web/

Comment: yes, it really works. Thanks. But I still have a problem because not all the files needed for the js-code get into build
I have to import each of them manually into index.html And it's very inconvenient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to cope with this problem, although it was not easy. It was necessary to wrap the response in `promiseToFeature` and `allowInterop`

index.html

```html
<script>
        var bridge = window.webBridgeInstance;
        async function sendBotEvent(eventObject) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve('done!');
                }, 1500);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    reject('err rejected!');
                }, 2500);
            });
        }
</script>
```

api_client.dart

```js
@JS()
library main;

import 'dart:js' as js;

typedef Callback<T> = dynamic Function(T arg);

@JS()
class Promise<T> {
  external Promise<T> then(Callback<T> successCallback,
      [Function errorCallback]);

  external Promise<T> catchIt(Function errorCallback);
}

@JS('sendBotEvent')
external Promise<dynamic> sendBotEvent(Object objectParams);

class SmartAppClient {
  Future<String> get(String endpoint, Object params) async {
    return await promiseToFuture(sendBotEvent({
      'method': 'get_$endpoint',
      'params': params,
    }).then(js.allowInterop((data) {
      print('SUCCESS: $data');
      return data;
    }), js.allowInterop((err) {
      print('ERROR: $err');
      return err;
    })));
  }
}
```

run:

```js
void testSmartappFuncs() async {
    await SmartAppClient()
        .get(
          'urlString',
          {},
        )
        .then((value) {
          print('RESULT RESULT RESULT');
          print(value);
        })
        .catchError((onError) {
          print('ERROR ERROR ERROR');
          print(onError);
        });
  }
```